# OdbcConnection Microsoft Excel Driver reading only first row first column

Tags: c#

My C# code is working for an excel file and is reading all lines but for another file it is reading only first row and first column.
Connection String:

```
sConnStr1 = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Dbq=" + info1.FullName + ";DefaultDir=" + info1.Directory + ";";
```

Code:

```
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn;
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter da;
    string file = sFilePath;
        conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConnStr1);
        da = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sDAstr1, conn);
        da.Fill(dt1);
```

Can someone please guide me. This is last problem I am facing to complete my application.

Answer (score 0):

Code above should work unless you are having a specific format in excel. Below is a sample code I have tried opening multiple excel files and is working.

```
    try
        {

            string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\Temp\temp.xlsx;";

            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection connection;
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable("excelImport");
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter;

            string m_selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            connection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            dataAdapter = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(m_selectSQL, connection);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```